# Recursive definitions in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How would I write a recursive definition in Prolog to create an alternating list in the following way :

`alternate(K, L, M)` holds if the list `M` is obtained by taking
elements alternately from the lists `K` and `L`, e.g.:

```
?- alternate([1,2,3,4,5,6],[a,b,c],Zs).

Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5, 6]
```

Also, if one list is longer than the other, then the remaining elements
of the longer list appear at the end of the result, `M` .

My attempt for this problem is the following but it is not working:

```
alternate([],L,L).
alternate(K, [], K).
alternate([Firstk|Restk], [Firstl|Restl], M):-
   K is [Firstk|Restk], L is [Firstl|Restl],
   M is [M|[Firstk]], K is Restk,
   M is [M|[Firstl]], L is Restl,
   alternate(K, L, M).
```

Any hints or suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the other answers, especially the one by @tas. But still, this approach feels too... "small-step". If you are processing *two* lists and are supposed to pick elements from each, why not pick those two elements simultaneously instead of picking from only one and swapping the lists? That feels like an "algorithm", not like a logical, declarative description of a relation.

So I propose the following:

```
alternate([], Ys, Ys).
alternate([X|Xs], [], [X|Xs]).
alternate([A | As], [B | Bs], [A, B | ABs]) :-
    alternate(As, Bs, ABs).
```

The general case, alternating two non-empty lists, is covered by the third clause: The first two elements of the alternated list are the first elements of the two lists to be alternated. The first two clauses just deal with the case where one or the other of the lists is empty. (You could add @tas's `islist` goals to these to enforce that the other argument really is a proper list.)

Here are the tests:

```
?- alternate([1,2,3,4,5,6],[a,b,c],Zs).
Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5, 6] ;
false.

?- alternate([1,2,3],[a,b,c,d,e,f],Zs).
Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, d, e, f].

?- alternate(Xs, Ys, [1,a,2,b,3,c]).
Xs = [],
Ys = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
Xs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c],
Ys = [] ;
Xs = [1],
Ys = [a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
Xs = [1, 2, b, 3, c],
Ys = [a] ;
Xs = [1, 2],
Ys = [a, b, 3, c] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 3, c],
Ys = [a, b] ;
Xs = [1, 2, 3],
Ys = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

(In SWI-Prolog, which only indexes on the first argument, this leaves slightly more choice points than some alternatives.)

Answer (score 4):

You could describe this relation by flipping the first two arguments in the recursive call, as suggested by @WillNess in the comments. And since the two lists can differ in length it would be helpful to have a predicate that describes lists in general to avoid matching arbitrary terms in the non-recursive rule. It would also be nice to have a somewhat more descriptive name that reflects the relational nature of the predicate. Taking all this into account the predicate might look something like this:

```
islist([]).
islist([_|T]) :-
   islist(T).

list_list_interlocked([],L,L) :-
   islist(L).
list_list_interlocked([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :-
   list_list_interlocked(Ys,Xs,Zs).
```

Your example query  works as expected:

```
?- list_list_interlocked([1,2,3,4,5,6],[a,b,c],Zs).
Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5, 6].
```

The predicate also works if the second list is longer:

```
?- list_list_interlocked([1,2,3],[a,b,c,d,e,f],Zs).
Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, d, e, f].
```

And it only works with lists:

```
?- list_list_interlocked(definitelynolist,[],Zs).
false.

?- list_list_interlocked([],definitelynolist,Zs).
false.
```

The latter is the reason why you need `islist/1`. If you define the non-recursive rule like this: `list_list_interlocked([],L,L).` then Prolog can unify arbitrary terms with `L` and the query would yield an incorrect result:

```
?- list_list_interlocked([],definitelynolist,Zs).
Zs = definitelynolist.
```

The predicate can also be used in the other direction, e.g. *What lists yield `[1,a,2,b,3,c]` when interlocked?*:

```
?- list_list_interlocked(X,Y,[1,a,2,b,3,c]).
X = [],
Y = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
X = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c],
Y = [] ;
X = [1],
Y = [a, 2, b, 3, c] ;
X = [1, 2, b, 3, c],
Y = [a] ;
X = [1, 2],
Y = [a, b, 3, c] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, c],
Y = [a, b] ;
X = [1, 2, 3],
Y = [a, b, c] ;
false.
```

Comment: `islist([a|nonlist]).` list?

Comment: @false: How very sloppy of me, I didn't consider that possibility. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed my code :-)

Comment: I would not call it sloppy as it might ensure termination at the price of over-generalization. I only complained about calling it list.

Answer (score 1):

Just write two predicates where one call the other and viceversa, like this:

```
alternate1([],[],[]).
alternate1([],L,L).
alternate1([H|T],L,[H|T1]):-
    alternate2(T,L,T1).
alternate2([],[],[]).
alternate2(L,[],L).
alternate2(L,[H|T],[H|T1]):-
    alternate1(L,T,T1).

?- alternate1([1,2,3,4,5,6],[a,b,c],Zs).
Zs = [1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, 5, 6]
false
```

Comment: what if you switch the 1st and the 2nd argument to `alternate2` consistently, throughout its definition? you'll end up with an equivalent predicate. will there be something interesting to say about this new predicate?